# Using parameter that would fetch data from another api based on a condition react native?

Tags: react-native, fetch, react-navigation

I have two pages Portfolio.js and PortfolioDetails.js. In the Portfolio.js file, I am fetching data from my api and displaying all the portfolios in a list. When I click on portfolio, it should take me to the PortfolioDetails screen, which will display only those stocks from stock api which are in the portfolio.

e.g if I click on Portfolio with id 1, it should filter out stocks from stock api which has portfolio id 1 and display all those stocks on the screen.

So far, I am successful in fetching both the apis and also when I click on one portfolio, it passes the portfolio id parameter to my PortfolioDetails screen. I am stuck where I have to filter the stocks to display based on this passed parameter - id.

Portfolio.js file

```
export default class Portfolio extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      title: "Portfolio",
      header: null,
    };
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      PortfolioSource: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/portfolios/")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          PortfolioSource: responseJson
        })
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error)) //to catch the errors if any
  }

  FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{
        height: .5,
        width: "100%",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
      }}
      />
    );
  }

  renderItem = (data) =>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.list} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push('Details', { portid: data.item.id })} >
      <Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.id}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.portfolio_id}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.name}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.description}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.gains}</Text></TouchableOpacity>

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.loader}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0c9" />
        </View>
      )
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.PortfolioSource}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
          renderItem={item => this.renderItem(item)}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}

        />

      </View>
    )
  }

}
```

PortfolioDetails.js

```
export default class PortfolioDetails extends React.Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            title: "PortfolioDetails",
            header: null,
        };
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            PortfolioDetailsdataSource: [],
        };
    }

componentDidMount() {


        fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/stocks/`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    loading: false,
                    PortfolioDetailsdataSource: responseJson
                })
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error)) //to catch the errors if any
    }

    FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
        return (
            <View style={{
                height: .5,
                width: "100%",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
            }}
            />
        );
    }

    goToPrevScreen = () => {
        this.props.navigation.goBack();
    }


    renderItem = (data) =>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.list}>
            <Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.id}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.ticker}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.price}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.market_cap}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.YTD}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.OneYear}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.TwoYear}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.TTM_Sales_Growth}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.PE_Ratio}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>


    render() {


        if (this.state.loading) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.loader}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0c9" />
                </View>
            )
        }
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.PortfolioDetailsdataSource}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
                    renderItem={item => this.renderItem(item)}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
                />


                <Text> portid: {this.props.navigation.state.params.portid} </Text>

                <Button
                    onPress={() => this.goToPrevScreen()}
                    title="go back to Portfolio"
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .find(). For example:

```
PortfolioDetailsDataSource.find(item => item.id === this.props.navigation.state.params.portId)
```

Assuming IDs are unique, this will return the desired object, otherwise it will return the first occurrence that passes the condition.

Comment: Pretty new to react. so should I be using the above .find() function in my renderItem function or while fetching the data from stocks api?

Comment: You can add it in .then() where you set the result with setState as following: this.setState({portfolioDetailsDataSource: responseJson.find(...)}). Use this if you do not need the other objects from the response.

Comment: Still not able to figure out. I am using something like this, but I am pretty sure there is some error here, the data is not being fetched.                                                 this.setState({
                    loading: false,
                    portfolioDetailsDataSource: responseJson.find(response => response.results.portfolio === this.props.navigation.state.params.portid)
                }) *portfolio is the id variable for portfolio in stock api which i need to match with portid parameter

Comment: Could you give an example of the object you receive from the API?

Comment: portfolio api [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "portfolio_id": "P1",
        "name": "Ecommerce",
        "description": "Global top 20 ecommerce companies",
        "holdings_path": "empty",
        "issue_date": "2019-08-30T05:05:48.193092Z",
        "gains": 0.0
    }, ]  stock api [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "ticker": "GOOGL",
        "price": 1200.0,
        "market_cap": 850.0,
        "YTD": 0.19,
        "OneYear": 0.23,
        "TwoYear": 0.32,
        "TTM_Sales_Growth": 0.22,
        "PE_Ratio": 25.0,
        "portfolio": [
            4
        ]
    }]

Comment: I am passing id from portfolio api to the next screen. while fetching stock api, I need to make sure it matches the portfolio array field from stock api. and fetch only those stocks which is a part of portfolio with id 1. The above stock is part of only portfolio 4, so when I click portfolio 4, it should show me that stock and any other other stock which has 4 in their portfolio field

Comment: The portfolio property is an array containing ids, therefore you need to do some more operations.

responseJson.filter(item => item.portfolio.find(p => p === portId))

This should return all objects containing the portfolioId in the ("portfolio": []) property

You should also check .map(), .find(), .filter() functions in the JS documentation for further problems to come :)